# Number definitions using math calculations in PHP

Tags: php, math, variables, numbers

I noticed that many developers use Math operations as variable values, like:

`$time = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;  // 7 days`

instead of just assigning the computed value

`$time = 604800;`

I know it makes the code more easy to understand, but won't this affect performance?
Do you think it's a good practice to do this?

Comment: It won't impact performance in any way that you should be concerned about.

Comment: readability is more important than micro optimization, unless your running your server on a 286.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a compiled language there would be no performance penalty as the calculation would be done at compile time. PHP generally is not compiled so there's probably a small performance penalty. In most cases I would prefer more readable code to higher performance (unless the code becomes a bottleneck). So DON'T worry about performance in this case.

Now if we compare your examples then

```
$time = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
```

is self explanatory even without a comment. If you write

```
$time = 604800;
```

then it's not obvious, what the value represents. Now, you could add a comment and write

```
$time = 604800; // 7 days in seconds
```

but this is bad for two reasons:

1. you are duplicating information, which is maybe not a big problem in itself, but
2. if you change the value without a modifying a comment, then you have harmful comment in your code. This is much bigger problem and is really caused by information duplication.

Answer (score 3):

It may affect performance, but we're talking about something so minuscule that it's not even worth considering (for probably 99.9% of all PHP applications).

I consider it good practice because if you want to bump up the value to 8 days, you don't have to recalculate everything, and can just change *7* to *8*.

Answer (score 2):

php is not the language to worry about the implications of such micro optimizations. I prefer readability unless theres a large performance penalty. This is rare.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about performance issues with this. It's a very simple math problem, and the advantage of knowing what the number represents far outweighs the performance of this extremely small operation.

That said, if you're using it within a loop, I'd calculate it first

```
$time = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // 7 days

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
{
    echo $time;
}
```